# linear conditional constraints

Tags: optimization

I would like to linearize the following for an optimization problem
if $(r1>r2)$  then $s1>s2$

$r1$ and $r2$ are integer variables in $[1,30]$

$s1$ and $s2$ are variables to be optimized that are continuous decimals in $[0,1]$

a not working suggestion:
$$
r1-r2\geq(30\cdot d1-29) ,
$$
$$
s1-s2\geq((1+0.0001)\cdot d1-1)
$$

what is wrong with my linear form?

Comment: As `r1` and `r2` are constants, you can do the `if` in advance. No need to bother the solver with this, so no need to linearize.

Comment: thank u...am now facing another case where r1 and r2 are variables. any idea?